# Modify controller to write some data to a log file every second

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm a Rails developer but I need to modify the controller of an application to save some sensors data to an external file.

I have this controller that take some data and populate a TableView, and data are updated every time I push a button in my view.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var currentNames: [Any] = [], voltageNames: [Any] = [], thermalNames: [Any] = []
    var currentValues: [Any] = [], voltageValues: [Any] = [], thermalValues: [Any] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        currentNames = currentArray()
        voltageNames = voltageArray()
        thermalNames = thermalArray()
        
        currentValues = returnCurrentValues()
        voltageValues = returnVoltageValues()
        thermalValues = returnThermalValues()
      
        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return currentNames.count
        case 1:
            return voltageNames.count
        case 2:
            return thermalNames.count
        default:
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        let string: NSMutableString = ""
    
        switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            // cell.textLabel.text =
            let name = currentNames[indexPath.row] as! NSString
            let number = currentValues[indexPath.row] as! NSNumber
            string.appendFormat("%@: %.2lf", name, number.doubleValue)
        case 1:
            let name = voltageNames[indexPath.row] as! NSString
            let number = voltageValues[indexPath.row] as! NSNumber
            string.appendFormat("%@: %.2lf", name, number.doubleValue)
        case 2:
            let name = thermalNames[indexPath.row] as! NSString
            let number = thermalValues[indexPath.row] as! NSNumber
            string.appendFormat("%@: %.2lf", name, number.doubleValue)

        default:
            break;
        }
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = string as String?

        return cell
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return "Current (A), \(currentNames.count) items"
        case 1:
            return "Voltage (V), \(voltageNames.count) items"
        case 2:
            return "Temperature (°C), \(thermalNames.count) items"
        default:
            return "";
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func reloadData(_ sender : AnyObject) {
        currentValues = returnCurrentValues()
        voltageValues = returnVoltageValues()
        thermalValues = returnThermalValues()

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I need to refresh data every second without pushing the button and I want to save this data in a log file.
I create a log.swift file

```
import Foundation

struct Log: TextOutputStream {

    func write(_ string: String) {
        let fm = FileManager.default
        let log = fm.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("log.txt")
        if let handle = try? FileHandle(forWritingTo: log) {
            handle.seekToEndOfFile()
            handle.write(string.data(using: .utf8)!)
            handle.closeFile()
        } else {
            try? string.data(using: .utf8)?.write(to: log)
        }
    }
}

var logger = Log()
```

I know that I can do something every second with

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { 
}
```

But I don't understand where to put this.

I just need to save a log with `thermalNames and thermalValues`
Basically the cell I have in my tableView

```
let name = thermalNames[indexPath.row] as! NSString
let number = thermalValues[indexPath.row] as! NSNumber
string.appendFormat("%@: %.2lf", name, number.doubleValue)
```

Then I will parse the file with ruby to convert to a csv...

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you have to create two functions. One for the action you want to perform and the other one for timer itself

here are the functions:

```
@objc func save() {
        //Your Saving action has to be here
    }
```

You have to call this one in ViewDidLoad

```
    func startTimerForShowScrollIndicator() {
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(self.save), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
```